# CSS class is ignored upon hosting

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a CSS file that holds all my css code for ten or so pages.

I am having issues with CSS classes being ignored.

I have p tags in the body that belong to their own class.

When testing on my local machine they work good and follow their own classes CSS.

However once I upload the site to my host the p tag's class is ignored and it follows the body's CSS.

Can someone please show me what I'm missing.

(Note I tested in Chrome and Safari)

HTML for p tag:

```
<p class="tinyText">Sample text here</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: black;
font-family: Papyrus;
font-size:20px;
color:white;

}

    .tinyText{

        font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
        font-size:20px;
    }
```

EDIT:

On hosted version, inspected element and followed CSS path. It is reading an old version of the CSS file. But the hosted version is the most updated, I double checked. I tried clearing cache and other data but its still getting that old version. How can I force it to get the new version?

Comment: may I see live demo plz

Comment: try your css as more specific ie :   p.tinyText { ... } instead of just .tinyText

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 0):

CSS Specificity is the answer (as to why your style is being overridden). An ID in the selector adds a higher specificity than your two-class style.

You need to either be more specific on your style (maybe add more classes or add more root elements to increase its value) or (as you mentioned) create an ID that would out-weigh the current stylesheet.

You can also use !important, but many would argue that as hack-ish considering it's primary intent is for client-side customizations (for accessibility).

Comment: Can't use Id, need to use class, multiple p tags

Answer (score 0):

You should add more css to the p element and see if it gets applied as now only there are two properties, one is font-size which is same as body and other is  font-family which you have set to Times New Roman, Times, serif. If these font is not available than it will take body font as fallback.

```
 .tinyText{

    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    /*add more css rules here*/
         }
```

Also do a hard refresh or open in incognito mode and do inspect element and see what all elements are coming and what rules are applied.

Also make sure css is called properly in header.

Also avoid using !important and use of ID.

Thanks

Comment: inspected element, under the style section on local it shows the body css and which properties are getting over riden by tinyText class. On hosted site tinyText class never makes an appearance

Comment: try avoiding capital in class Name .. jus keep it as tinytext.. at css and class declaration in html  Also add extra css rules that I asked you to i.e. color, large font-size, background etc..  Also please share hosted link if you can

Answer (score 0):

first thing you want to do is Create or use a CSS Reset sheet. here is a popular one.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

and add this to the top of your css file. 
Some browsers have their own settings for CSS so you always want to take this into account. Now what you want to do is always use inspect element and see if you can see any styles or CSS properties being applied to it.[image] Also use [codepen.io](http://codepen.io) this is a great website to link people to your issues and also use to see what things will look like

Answer (score -1):

try avoiding capital in class Name .. jus keep it as tinytext.. at css and class declaration in html

Comment: this is not an answer to the problem asked.